# Will one tourist visa for Brazil cover 2 visits?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, brazil

I am a citizen of the USA and I'm planning to be in Brazil for about 5 days on a cruise in November-December 2018. I then plan to do another land tour, which includes Brazil somewhere between January and March of 2019. Will one visa work for both trips?

Comment: Is your visa single- or multi-entry? The answer would totally depend on this.

Comment: Upload an image of your visa, blacking out personal information

Answer (score 1):

The answer should be yes. If you have applied for a tourist visa these are given with a validity of 10 years (the old, traditional visas) or 2 years (the new e-visas coming online soon). Both are valid for multiple entries. See [here](https://brazil.visahq.com/) for more information and information on other types of visas.